# Getting \bm to pass thru siunitx macros

Tags: siunitx, bold

It seems that macros form the `\siunitx` package have a `\bm` problem, but no problem with `\textcolor`:

[image]

Note that the `180` passed thru the `\ang` macro is not bold.

So, how do I change the `\MyFormat` macro so that `\bm` passes thru the `siunitx` macros.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand*{\MyFormat}[2][blue]{\bm{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}}%

\begin{document}

\[ 
    \MyFormat{\frac{180}{\pi}} = \MyFormat{\frac{\ang{180}}{\pi}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Colour and font weight are treated differently as `siunitx` deliberately resets the font, but does nothing to the colour.

Comment: I ran that document with \tracingall but decided to go home rather than look at it, thankfully someone else answered. You should try it:-) `\ang` is more complicated than it looks (and so is `\bm for that matter:-)`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Wow!! With just the `siunitx` package and the document consisting only of `\ang{180}` I get a 5.4MB file with `\tracingall`.  ...Well, if have just the package included and an completely empty document I still get a 4.7MB file!!  How can you possibly debug with `\tracingall`?

Comment: The log file looks a bit scary at first but nothing looks too bad once you have it safely in an emacs buffer.

Comment: @PeterGrill There's a lot of font switching going on. You are best off with the `trace` package and `\traceon`. (Of course, I have the advantage of knowing where to look in the first place, at least in theory.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can configure the [`siunitx`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) package to detect bold math. Try

```
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
```

For in-line formulae, you additionally need:

```
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}
```

Comment: To elaborate a little, `siunitx` can deal with math mode material either as 'matching' the surrounds or as 'independent'. With the standard settings, it ignores font changes entirely. If you turn on weight detection, math material is as standard treated as 'matching' the text it is within.