# SI inserts line break before unit

Tags: line-breaking, siunitx, bold

Not sure what has changed with `siunitx` but for some reason the

```
\let\text\textbf
```

is causing a line break *before* the unit is output by the `\SI{<value>}{<unit>}` macro when invoked *outside* of math mode. Problem text is in blue:

[image]

I have had this code for several years now and have noticed this problem until now.

I have only noticed this problem with the `\SI{}{}` macro. Are there other macros that would exhibit similar issues?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64547/getting-bm-to-pass-thru-siunitx-macros
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}

\newcommand\SetInBoldFont[2]{%
    \begingroup
        \let\text\textbf%
        \bm{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}%
    \endgroup
}
    
\def\SIText{\SI{1}{\kilo\meter}}

\begin{document}
In math mode things work fine:
\SetInBoldFont{red}{%
\[
    \SIText \text{ where $\si{\kilo\meter}$ is kilometers}
\]
}
Inline math also works: $\SetInBoldFont{red}{\SIText}$

Outside of math mode things break:
\SetInBoldFont{blue}{\SIText}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\SIrange` seems to show linebreaks occur before and *after* the unit.

Comment: Minor observation: replacing `\let\text\textbf` by `\long\def\text##1{\leavevmode##1}` also causes the line-break.  Haven't tracked down further.

Comment: Additional hint (found by running your `\SIText` inside and outside an `\hbox` with `\loggingall` and diffing the logs): `\__siunitx_ensure_ltr:n` calls `\color@endgroup` which includes a call to `\endgraf`, responsible it seems for the linebreak.

Comment: I'm not sure what an answer would be here. The semantics of `\text` and `\textbf` are very different and so swapping one for another is likely to cause unexpected outcomes: 'do not do this' perhaps?

Comment: the code here is er interesting,  you don't say what it's supposed to do, can't you just use `\boldmath` to make math bold rather than trying to fit the entire expression in `bm` ?

Comment: Well, `\let\text\textbf` is wrong to begin with: not conceptually, but technically (refer to `letltxmacro`).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I need both the math and any `\text{}` in the math to be bold. I thought a simple redefinition of `\text` would do.

Comment: why redefine anything,  `\bfseries\boldmath $ bold \text{bold}$ bold}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I thought `\bfseries` could only be used in text mode? and `\boldmath` could only be used in math mode?  Can you post an answer as my initial attempt did not work.

Comment: @egreg: DId not realize that there were optional paramaters here. I did try using `\LetLtxMacro` but that yeielded `TeX capacity exceeded`.

Comment: \boldmath can only be used *outside* mathmode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to Ulrike’s solution, but more robust, see the final part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64547/getting-bm-to-pass-thru-siunitx-macros
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}

\newcommand\SetInBoldFont[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \ifmmode
      \textcolor{#1}{\bm{{#2}}}%
    \else
    \renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{\bfdefault}%
    \bfseries\boldmath\textcolor{#1}{#2}%
    \fi
  \endgroup
}

\def\SIText{\SI{1}{\kilo\meter}}

\begin{document}
In math mode things work fine:
\SetInBoldFont{red}{%
\[
    \SIText \text{ where $\si{\kilo\meter}$ is kilometers}
\]
}
Inline math also works: $\SetInBoldFont{red}{\SIText}$

Outside of math mode things don't break:
\SetInBoldFont{blue}{\SIText}

\textit{\SetInBoldFont{blue}{This is in italics \SIText}}

\SetInBoldFont{blue}{\textit{This is in italics \SIText}}

\SetInBoldFont{blue}{\normalfont\itshape This is in italics \SIText}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, `\let\text\textbf` is wrong under many respects. The main one is the usual business described in the documentation of `letltxmacro`. Here, however, there's a much more important aspect.

How does `amstext` (that’s loaded by `amsmath` and is responsible for defining `\text`) makes `\textbf` to change size when in subscripts or superscripts? Well, if `\textbf{foo}` appears in math mode, LaTeX executes `\nfss@text{\textbf{foo}}` and `\nfss@text` is `\mbox` when `amstext` is not loaded. But `amstext` does `\let\nfss@text\text`: can you see the infinite loop? `;-)`

Comment: I used \color instead of \textcolor as I had the impression from one of the comments from Peter that one should consider the case that the argument contains a \par.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In that case `\leavevmode` is necessary before `\color`.

Comment: In which cases outside tabular would it matter?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Any time the command is issued in vertical mode.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not feeling at all comfortable with the way you are putting a whole display math and even normal text in a `\bm` argument. Imho you should at least try to detect math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64547/getting-bm-to-pass-thru-siunitx-macros
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}

\newcommand\SetInBoldFont[2]{%    
    \begingroup
    \color{#1}%
    \ifmmode
     \bm{{#2}}% either additonal braces here or at use around fragile commands.
    \else
     \bfseries\mathversion{bold}#2
    \fi
    \endgroup
}

\def\SIText{\SI{1}{\kilo\meter}}

\begin{document}
In math mode things work fine:
\SetInBoldFont{red}{%
\[
   \SIText \text{ where $\si{\kilo\meter}$ is kilometers}
\]
}
Inline math also works: $\SetInBoldFont{red}{\SIText} $

And Outside of math mode: \SetInBoldFont{blue}{\SIText}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This also works, but I am not understanding how the test for `immode` is execute outside of math mode and yet it still results in the correct output?

Answer (score 3):

Another "idiot solution", which simply uses text mode in all cases. This approach also simplifies the `\sisetup` stuff.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,siunitx}

\newcommand\SetInBoldFont[2]{%
     \begingroup
     \sisetup{detect-weight}%
     \textbf{\color{#1}#2}%
     \endgroup}
\def\SIText{\SI{1}{\kilo\meter}}

\begin{document}
In display math things work fine:
\[\SetInBoldFont{red}{\SIText}\]

In inline math things work too: 
$\SetInBoldFont{purple}{\SIText}$

In text mode things are also fine:
\SetInBoldFont{blue}{\SIText}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\text{\bfseries\color{#1}#2}`.  Why not just `\textbf{\color{#1}#2}`?

Comment: @HenriMenke - Even simpler! I'll make the change right away.

Comment: Probably you could even `\textbf{\sisetup{detect-weight}\color{#1}#2}` and remove `\begin...\endgroup` :)

Comment: @HenriMenke - :-) I'll leave it to the OP to decide how much he wants to compress the code...

Comment: I don't quite like how you have changed the syntax of how the display math was highlighted. I prefer to invoke `\SetInBoldFont{}` outside of the display math as there may be text before and after the display math.

Comment: @PeterGrill - `\SetInBoldFont{red}{\[\SIText\]}` ("new syntax") appears to create the same output as `\[\SetInBoldFont{red}{\SIText}\]` ("old syntax") does. Similarly, `\[\SetInBoldFont{red}{\SIText\text{ where $\si{\kilo\meter}$ is kilometers}}\]` and `\SetInBoldFont{red}{\[\SIText\text{ where $\si{\kilo\meter}$ is kilometers}\]}` appear to produce the same output. In short, I don't think the change in syntax is significant. Can you maybe provide a more relevant example where the "new syntax" breaks down?

Comment: @Mico: Yep, you are correct, seems to work fine. Same question as Henri's solution: Can you explain how the `\text{\bfseries}` retains the `\bfseries` setting for the subsequent invocation of `\text{}` in display mode?

Comment: @PeterGrill - It was upon seeing Henri Menke's answer (which includes the `\text{\bfseries}` code snippet) that I decided to post another "idiot" answer. I, too, don't understand how or why the `\text{\bfseries}` directive "works". You ought to ask Henri (again) to explain how and why his code works...